# How to choose output length based on whether or not first character is a letter?

Tags: sql

I am trying to return a column in sql
which should return 4 characters from the column when the character starts with an alphabet, for a numeric it should return only 3 characters .
Eg:

```
column:
B98497
C68756
r45789
123467
578912
```

output:
the above column should return the following

```
column:
B984
C687
r457
123
578
```

I used the following code but it returns only first three characters
my code:

```
select substring(column,1,3)
from table
```

the output for my code:

```
column
B98
C68
r45
123
578
```

how do I get an output like this:

```
B984
C687
r457
123
578
```

Comment: Use a case expression to decide if it should be 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is used?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. I removed these conflicting tags, please tag only one database.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use MySQL 8.0, there's a one-liner:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '[a-z]?[0-9]{3}') FROM Table1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/etYB7DYKDhpAyARpeiXPW6/0). And here's the corresponding [docpage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr).

If it's 5.7, you have to check the first symbol against letter character class, like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(column1, IF(column1 RLIKE '^[a-z]', 4, 3)) FROM Table1;
```

... which can actually be simplified as showed in @GordonLinoff answer.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rmK9Yv9sXzmZ4Wdk6RaZWN/0).

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select left(col, 3 + (col rlike '^[a-zA-Z'))
```

This uses the fact that boolean expressions evaluate to 1 or 0 in a number context.

Answer (score 0):

**Following Should Do**

```
select 
CASE WHEN substring(TheColumn, 1,1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN substring(TheColumn, 1,3)
ELSE substring(TheColumn, 1, 4) END
from [dbo].[TabAlpNum]
```